# Как создать многомерный массив с ключами?

Tags: python, массивы

Хочу написать небольшой скрипт на python. Язык знаю посредственно, а сделать охота быстро.
Как создать многомерный массив с ключами? Что-то вроде такого:

```
 А = [ 0 : [ [1,3] ,[2,4] ],
       3 : [ [4,3] ,[5,4] ],
      75 : [ [10,3] ,[20,4] ] ]
```

Для понятности: нужно в цикле забивать кортежи (кортежи ли? - я не дока) в цикле по принципу
имеем 3 строки из базы - ид, значение, время
и должны получить удобоваримый массив, чтобы можно было записать отдельно массивы с разными ид,
то есть:

```
  massiv = {
            id_1 : [ [val_11, time_11], [val_21, time_21] ],
            id_2 : [ [val_12, time_12], [val_22, time_22] ],
            id_3 : [ [val_13, time_13], [val_23, time_23] ]
           }
что то вроде

for i in len(id):

    massiv(id[i] : { [ val[i], time[i] ] }
```

Comment: @anunak, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
A = {
  0: [[1, 3], [2, 4]],
  3: [[4, 3], [5, 4]],
  75: [[10, 3], [20, 4]]
}
```

Comment: так не ответ же. создать словарь то можно. а вот как его заполнить то? 
keys =[1,3,4]
A = []
for key in keys:
A[key] = [[1, 21], [2, 22]]
print(A)

что-то не очень хочет работать.

Comment: @anunak, `A = {}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
                        a = dict()
                        id = [1,2,3,1,1]
                        val = [1,3,4,5,5]
                        time = [5,6,7,6,5]
                        for i in range(len(id)):
                            try:
                                a[id[i]].append((val[i], time[i]))
                            except KeyError:
                                a[id[i]] = [(val[i], time[i])]
                        print(a[1][0][0])
                        print(a)
```

1

{1: [(1, 5), (5, 6), (5, 5)], 2: [(3, 6)], 3: [(4, 7)]}

---

еще лучше

```
            from collections import defaultdict

            a = defaultdict(list)
            id = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1]
            val = [1, 3, 4, 5, 5]
            time = [5, 6, 7, 6, 5]
            for i in range(len(id)):
                a[id[i]].append((val[i], time[i]))

            for k in a.keys():
                print(k, a[k])
```

Comment:     for i in id:
        a[i] = a.get(i, []).append( (val[i], time[i]) );